# Django - Displaying users dropdown list in Template from ModelForm

Tags: django

i have a Model field called `Followed_By` which is a TextField, the thing i'm facing is when i try to to use Template from ModelForm, the Data is not being saved, i think the error i'm making is in the dropdown list of the template because when i replace the dropdown list with normal input tag of type text then all work fine, my template is:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
   <label for="{{form.Followed_By.name}}">Follower</label>
   <select id="{{form.Followed_By.name}}" name="Followed_By" class="form control" value="{{form.Followed_By.value|default_if_none:""}}">
   <option>{{John}}</option>
   <option>{{Bale}}</option>       
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not just let the form render the field with `{{ form.Followed_By }}`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Followed_By  is a text field in model but a select dropdown in template. Does he not have to customize the widget field of the field Followed_BY if he does {{ form.Followed_By }}?

Comment: In the code above <option>{{John}}</option> is wrong. It should be something like <option value="{{John}}">John</option>. You must specify the value attribute of the each option.

Comment: @ChetanGanji, your way worked just fine! but now the thing is when i use the same template from update view it does not show the current value, any idea please?

Comment: What you are looking for is selected attribute on the option element e.g. <option value="fiat" selected>Fiat</option>

Comment: in your case, it would be something like below

Comment: <option value="John" 
    {% if form.Followed_By.value == "John" %}
        {{ "selected" }}
    {% endif %}>
    John
</option>

Comment: You could also do it when you instantiate the form e.g. form = WhateverForm(initial={'Followed_By': 'John'})
This way is preferred as it does not require to add any more template code. But the value 'John' needs to be read dynamically (from database) in this case.